# gitignore file for SQL Server project: SSIS / SSAS / SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, git, visual-studio, ssis, ssas

There's a git ignore pattern for all the Visual Studio projects on GitHub: [gitignore/VisualStudio.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore). But I'm working specifically for SQL Server Business Intelligence solution in VS, and it seems that files like `*.ispac` are not ignored. Is there any more specific pattern available for these projects ?

- SSIS
- SSAS
- SSRS

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I did some googling this morning on this and I found the following file.  It looks pretty complete so I will give it a try.  The *.ispac files are in the bin directory so they should be ignored anyway thanks to the rule for ignoring bin and obj.

https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudio

Comment: I don't work with MSBI anymore. Did you apply this `.gitignore` file to a MSBI project, which one precisely? Did you try it with multiple Git repos to see check the correctness of such git ignore file? If yes, I can accept your answer.

Comment: Yes I am using the file in a SSIS project in VS 2015 (SQL Server 2016).  Sorry just the one git repo but it is working correctly on multiple peoples repos.  It is ignoring everything it should and working as expected.

Comment: For others, this is sourced from here :
https://github.com/github/gitignore/

see the VisualStudio.gitignore file